# in a Google Form, can I change or remove a question safely after receiving responses/Submissions?

Tags: google-forms

After I create my Google Form and start to receive submissions,

- can I change or remove a question or will it break the data?

I know it's very picky with having to re-link the spreadsheet if I link one and I make a change while designing the form.
What about the Responses saved "inside the form"?
Are they impacted if I change or remove a question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**It will indeed remove the data in the Responses saved "inside" the Form**

You must be very careful about maintaining your data after you start to receive submissions/Responses.

All data is tied to a specific Question Item.  As you see in any linked Sheet, if you even change the text of the Question, the link is broken.
This does also happen "inside" the stored Form responses.

**You cannot change or remove questions in a Form and get at the data again in the Form Response.**
Make sure you have all the data pulled out from the Form before making changes.  If you have a Linked Sheet, make sure to back it up, and be prepared to re-link and merge with a new Sheet.